# System.EntryPointNotFoundException when loading Sitecore 9.0

Tags: configuration, tds, visual-studio

On Sitecore 9.0, when I attempt to load any URL, I get an Owin startup exception with the following details:

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
- No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.
- The discovered startup type 'Sitecore.Owin.Startup, Sitecore.Owin, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' conflicts with the type 'SolrNet.Startup, SolrNet, Version=0.4.0.2002, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Remove or rename one of the types, or reference the desired type directly. To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config. To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or configuration method name in your web.config.
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an indication on Sitecore 9 that your `Web.config` has been overwritten. Check the deployed `Web.config`, replace it with the stock 9.0 version if needed, and/or ensure your Visual Studio solution is configured to deploy the proper `Web.config`. It could be that one was added to a web app project after installing a nuget package. If you're using TDS, try setting the *Build Action* to *None* on `Web.config` files which you do not wish to deploy.

Answer (score 3):

I have resolved the issue with @techphoria441 answer.

Ensure that all your projects web.config **Build Action** is set to **None**.

[image]